# Callout control in blend not exist anymore?

Tags: silverlight, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, expression-blend

I am doing a Win store app 8.1. I want to have a shape looks like the dialog box, with the little triangle in the bottom. I remember there is "Callout" control in Expression 4 before when I did WP7 silverlight app, which is the thing I want, but they are not existing any more in blend for win store apps.

Where can I find that shape, Any ideas?

Comment: I guess I hadn't looked but yea it doesn't seem to be in the Shapes menu like you'd expect. However if the placement of the little triangle is always the same then it would be really easy to just make your own. Just draw a rectangle, then a triangle with your pen tool, then select both and Object->Combine->Unite

Answer (score 0):

Stinks huh? But maybe it's not what you would have wanted anyway, right? Listen, there's nothing stopping you from creating one. It's super-easy.

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/expression-design-to-create-windows-8.html

Here's another one

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/you-can-make-it-snow-in-xaml-here-ill.html

Best of luck!